# Batch File to silently auto-install Java

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, installation

I am writing a Batch to auto-install Modded Minecraft (included everything needed). Installing Java seemed simple enough but I can't figure out how to install it silently with something like wget.

Example:

```
wget {java download link}
/s java-installer.exe (basically run it silently)
then wait for it to install (which I also can't find a good way)
if exist "java.exe" (goto java-installed) else (goto java-install-failed)
then on to the rest of my code
```

(Any answers are appreciated)

I tried to install java from the installer file in the batch but it just opens the file. I don't really know where to go from there. The ideal process would silently installed it and output the info from the java installer to the same command prompt window and the batch file

Comment: Try with java-installer.exe /s

Comment: The first thing I'd mention is, to the best of my knowledge, for at least a few years now, Oracle forbids anyone from downloading Java in such a manner. Then I'd say the best way is to use a configuration file for installation. Additionaly, the installation options are clearly listed all over the internet, not just for the specific application if using an .exe file, but for Microsoft installers, i.e. .msi files. You have not even told us which you are trying to install, or how the download is working for you. We expect you to submit code and debugging information.